# Unsmooth scrolling

Tags: scrolling

I noticed since the first time I used Ubuntu that scrolling up and down with the mouse wheel seems a bit unresponsive compared to on Windows. It still works but the difference is noticeable. Does anyone else also have this issue or know how to address it?

Comment: Does the screen take a moment to scroll but once it starts it goes smoothly, or do you mean the screen tears as you're scrolling?

Comment: Is this scrolling in Chrome you refer to?

Comment: @bc2946088
it takes a moment and once it goes, it/s somewhat smooth. if i stop for an instant, it may get stuck again. no screen tearing.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix 
this is scrolling in terminal